# Get class name using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to get the class name using jQuery

And if it has an id

```
<div class="myclass"></div>
```

Comment: @Amarghosh: True, true, but you could actually get into this situation, if you use some traversal methods like `parents()`.

Comment: fyi `this.className` works without jquery (would return `"myclass"` in above example)

Answer (score 1153, accepted):

After getting the element as jQuery object via other means than its class, then

```
var className = $('#sidebar div:eq(14)').attr('class');
```

should do the trick. For the ID use `.attr('id')`.

If you are inside an event handler or other jQuery method, where the element is the pure DOM node without wrapper, you can use:

```
this.className // for classes, and
this.id // for IDs
```

Both are standard DOM methods and well supported in all browsers.

Comment: and if its an ID
var IDName = $('#id').attr('id');

Comment: As sandino points out in his answer, there is always a chance of more than one class name being set. (for instance JQuery-UI adds helper classes all over the place).
You could always checked for this using 
`if(className.indexOf(' ') !== -1){throw new Error('Uh-oh! More than one class name!');}`

Comment: If you leverage `.attr('class')` and combine it with `if(className.indexOf('Class_I_am_Looking_For') > = 0)` you can easily check for the existence a specific class and still handle multiple classes.

Comment: RonnBlack: `if(className.indexOf('Class_I_am_Looking_For') > = 0)` will also match `"This_Is_Not_the_Class_I_am_Looking_For"`

Comment: you have to split on whitespace so:

function isClassInString(className, classToCheck) { 
var classes = className.split("\\s+");

for (var j=0; j<classes.length; j++) {
        if (classes[j].match(classToCheck)) return true;
    }
return false;
}

Comment: It’s time to come back here. The white-space splitting of `@class` was never an issue. This was, especially, not the original question. All the OP asked was, how to get the “class name”, which translates to “content of the `class` attribute” (as proven by accepting the answer). @sandino’s answer is good, but perhaps the use case of the OP was to copy classes from one element to another? In this case `.hasClass()` is virtually useless. Who knows?

Comment: What about with the this keyword? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22665134/getting-an-id-from-jquerys-this

Comment: @BenRacicot in that case, simply use [standard DOM methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className).

Comment: @Boldewyn I may be missing something here. If you already know the class name (e.g. myclass) what is the point of using this code?`$('.myclass').attr('class');`

Comment: You may be knowing _one_ of several class names. Or you do have another reference to that element, like `$(document.getElementById('foo'))`. This question and answer target specifically at how to learn _all_ classes, that a given element possesses. I agree, that the example is not chosen too luckily, though.

Answer (score 249):

It is better to use `.hasClass()` when you want to check if an element has a particular `class`. This is because when an element has multiple `class` it is not trivial to check.

**Example:**

```
<div id='test' class='main divhover'></div>
```

**Where:**

```
$('#test').attr('class');        // returns `main divhover`.
```

With `.hasClass()` we can test if the `div` has the class `divhover`.

```
$('#test').hasClass('divhover'); // returns true
$('#test').hasClass('main');     // returns true
```

Comment: But what if you *don't* know the classname? ;-)

Comment: that's right...this is only usefull if you know the classname you are checking...but my comment was to alert you not to use .attr('class')=='CLASSNAME_YOU_ARE_SEARCHING' to check if a dom element has some class instead it's better to use .hasClass

Comment: Another way is to use `.is('.divhover')`

Comment: Is it possible to loop over classes of an element?

Comment: Yes it is just do $(element).attr("class").split(' '); and you get a list then just use a for or foreach loop

Answer (score 48):

Be Careful , Perhaps , you have a class and a subclass .

```
  <div id='id' class='myclass mysubclass' >dfdfdfsdfds</div>
```

If you use  previous solutions , you will have :

```
myclass mysubclass
```

So if you want to have the **class selector**, do the following :

```
var className = '.'+$('#id').attr('class').split(' ').join('.')
```

and you will have

```
.myclass.mysubclass
```

Now if you want to select all elements that have the same class such as div above :

```
   var brothers=$('.'+$('#id').attr('class').split(' ').join('.'))
```

that means

```
var brothers=$('.myclass.mysubclass')
```

## Update 2018

OR can be implemented with vanilla javascript in 2 lines:

```
  const { classList } = document.querySelector('#id');
  document.querySelectorAll(`.${Array.from(classList).join('.')}`);
```

Comment: There may be more than one space between classes. More correct variant var className = '.'+$('#id').attr('class').replace(/ +(?= )/g,'').split(' ').join('.')

Comment: An even more correct expression is `'.'+$('#id').attr('class').split(/[ \n\r\t\f]+/).join('.')`, because [space, Tab, LF, CR and FF](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/infrastructure.html#space-character) are allowed to separate classes. (`.split()` also accepts RegExps.)

Comment: `'.'+$('#id').attr('class').split(/\s+/).join('.')` would be more concise, wouldn't it? Or would that match something I'm not thinking about?

Comment: To be safe and not get any trailing dot, with any of these solutions, add a trim like this `.attr('class').trim().split(...)`

Answer (score 31):

This is to get the second class into multiple classes using into a element

```
var class_name = $('#videobuttonChange').attr('class').split(' ')[1];
```

Answer (score 17):

you can simply use,

`var className = $('#id').attr('class');`

Answer (score 12):

If your `<div>` has an `id`:

```
​<div id="test" class="my-custom-class"></div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

...you can try:

```
var yourClass = $("#test").prop("class");
```

---

If your `<div>` has only a `class`, you can try:

```
var yourClass = $(".my-custom-class").prop("class");
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're going to use the split function to extract the class names, then you're going to have to compensate for potential formatting variations that could produce unexpected results.  For example:

```
" myclass1  myclass2 ".split(' ').join(".")
```

produces

```
".myclass1..myclass2."
```

I think you're better off using a regular expression to match on set of allowable characters for class names. For example:

```
" myclass1  myclass2  ".match(/[\d\w-_]+/g);
```

produces

```
["myclass1", "myclass2"]
```

The regular expression is probably not complete, but hopefully you understand my point.  This approach mitigates the possibility of poor formatting.

Answer (score 6):

To complete Whitestock answer (which is the best I found) I did :

```
className = $(this).attr('class').match(/[\d\w-_]+/g);
className = '.' + className.join(' .');
```

So for **" myclass1  myclass2  "** the result will be **'.myclass1 .myclass2'**

Answer (score 6):

```
<div id="elem" class="className"></div>
```

With Javascript

```
document.getElementById('elem').className;
```

With jQuery

```
$('#elem').attr('class');
```

OR

```
$('#elem').get(0).className;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get class Name by two ways :

```
var className = $('.myclass').attr('class');
```

OR

```
var className = $('.myclass').prop('class');
```

Answer (score 3):

If we have a code:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="myClass myClass2"></div>
```

to take class name by using jQuery we could define and use a simple plugin method:

```
$.fn.class = function(){
  return Array.prototype.slice.call( $(this)[0].classList );
}
```

or

```
 $.fn.class = function(){
   return $(this).prop('class');
 }
```

The use of the method will be:

```
$('#myDiv').class();
```

We have to notice that it will return a list of classes unlike of native method element.className which returns only first class of the attached classes. Because often the element has more than one class attached to it, I recommend you not to use this native method but element.classlist or the method described above.

The first variant of it will return a list of classes as an array, the second as a string - class names separated by spaces:

```
// [myClass, myClass2]
// "myClass myClass2"
```

Another important notice is that both methods as well as jQuery method

```
$('div').prop('class');
```

return only class list of the first element caught by the jQuery object if we use a more common selector which points many other elements. In such a case we have to mark the element, we want to get his classes, by using some index, e.g.

```
$('div:eq(2)').prop('class');
```

It depends also what you need to do with these classes. If you want just to check for a class into the class list of the element with this id you should just use method "hasClass":

```
if($('#myDiv').hasClass('myClass')){
   // do something
}
```

as mentioned in the comments above. But if you could need to take all classes as a selector, then use this code:

```
$.fn.classes = function(){
   var o = $(this);
   return o.prop('class')? [''].concat( o.prop('class').split(' ') ).join('.') : '';
 } 

 var mySelector = $('#myDiv').classes();
```

The result will be:

```
// .myClass.myClass2
```

and you could get it to create dynamically a specific rewriting css rule for example.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

If you do not know the class name BUT you know the ID you can try this:

```
<div id="currentST" class="myclass"></div>
```

Then Call it using :

```
alert($('#currentST').attr('class'));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get classes of div and then want to check if any class exists then simple use.

```
if ( $('#div-id' ).hasClass( 'classname' ) ) {
    // do something...
}
```

e.g;

```
if ( $('body').hasClass( 'home' ) ) {
    $('#menu-item-4').addClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try it**

**HTML**

```
<div class="class_area-1">
    area 1
</div>

<div class="class_area-2">
    area 2
</div>

<div class="class_area-3">
    area 3
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
    $('div').click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('class'));
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works too.

```
const $el = $(".myclass");
const className = $el[0].className;
```

Answer (score 0):

if we have single or we want first `div` element we can use

`$('div')[0].className` otherwise we need an `id` of that element

Answer (score 0):

**Best way to get class name in javascript or jquery**

**`attr()` attribute function is used to get and set attribute.**

---

> **Get Class**

```
jQuery('your selector').attr('class');  // Return class
```

---

> **Check class exist or not**

```
The hasClass() method checks if any of the selected elements have a specified class name.

 if(jQuery('selector').hasClass('abc-class')){
        // Yes Exist
    }else{
        // NOt exists
    }
```

---

> **Set Class**

```
jQuery('your selector').attr('class','myclass');  // It will add class to your selector
```

---

> **Get Class on Click of button using jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).on('click','button',function(){
     var myclass = jQuery('#selector').attr('class');
});
```

---

> **Add class if selector have no any class using jQuery**

```
if ( $('#div-id' ).hasClass( 'classname' ) ) {
        // Add your code
    }
```

---

> **Get the second class into multiple classes using into a element**

```
Change array position in place of [1] to get particular class.

var mysecondclass = $('#mydiv').attr('class').split(' ')[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

## Direct way

```
myid.className
```

```js
console.log( myid.className )
```

```html
<div id="myid" class="myclass"></div>
```

Answer (score -3):

use like this:-

```
$(".myclass").css("color","red");
```

if you've used this class more than once then use each operator

```
$(".myclass").each(function (index, value) {
//do you code
}
```