# Click button, display css class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

When I click button (eg.input type="button" class="test"), 
I want to display style sheet class name.

I already tried like this.

```
$(this).get(0).style.name
```

But i get only undefined message.
Please let me know how to get it.

@@Edit

Let me show you my coding.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>      
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-fieldselection.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var CurrentTextBoxID = "";          

        // toggles the keyboard to show or hide when link is clicked
        $(":text").focus(function(e) {              

            CurrentTextBoxID = this.id;
            var top = ($(window).height() - $('#keyboard').height()) - 25;        
            var left = ($(window).width() - $('#keyboard').width()) / 2;

            //alert(CurrentTextBoxID + " focus In");        
            $('#keyboard').css(
                {               
                    "left": left+"px",
                    "top": top+"px"
                }
            ).toggle();

            $('#keyboard').show();
        });


        //$(":text").focusout(function() {
        $(":text").focusout(function() {                

            alert($(this).attr('class'));

            if($(this).attr('class') != "testClass"){
                $('#keyboard').hide();
            }


        });

        // function thats called when any of the keys on the keyboard are pressed
        $("#keyboard input").bind("click", function(e) {                    
            $('#'+CurrentTextBoxID).replaceSelection($(this).val(), true);      
        }); 
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
#keyboard {
    position: fixed;
    background: #eee;
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius:7px;
    width: 700px;
    height: 240px;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: move;
    box-shadow: -5px -5px 5px 5px #888;
    -moz-border-radius: -5px -5px 5px 5px #888;
    -webkit-border-radius: -5px -5px 5px 5px #888;
}
.testClass{
    width: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="frmOnScreenKeyboard" name="frmOnScreenKeyboard">  

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="txtTest1" id="txtTest1"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="txtTest2" id="txtTest2"/>      
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="txtTest3" id="txtTest3"/>      
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="button" name="butButton1" id="butButton1"/>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="password" name="txtpassword1" id="txtpassword1"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<table>


<table height="900px">
</table>

<div id="keyboard">
    <table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="row2_shift">
                    <table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
                    <tr>                                
                        <td><input name="a" type="button" value="A" class="testClass" /></td>
                        <td><input name="s" type="button" value="S" class="testClass" /></td>
                        <td><input name="d" type="button" value="D" class="testClass" /></td>                                                           
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>               
    </table>        
</div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I use this code,

```
alert($(this).attr('class'));
```

I still get undefined message.
Please guide me again, Thank to all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400386/get-class-name-using-jquery

Comment: I finally found out that it already have not class which is why i cannot do it. Thank you everybody who give me answer back.

Answer (score 6):

Try this -

```
$(this).attr('class');
```

**EDIT**
This happens when the element does not have the class. You can check if the element has class as -

```
alert($(this).hasClass('classname'));
```

**EDIT2**

I added your code to JSFiddle and on focus out of first text box, you can see an alert with class name. Most important thing I observed is, none of your text inputs have a class attribute.

You can test at : http://jsfiddle.net/njJEg/4/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.test').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

jQuery `.attr('class')` will get the value of class attribute. However if the element doesn't have class attribute it will return `undefined` so make sure you have the class attribute set otherwise you can always check first using the following code:

```
if($(this).hasClass('yourClassValue')) {
    var myClass = $(this).attr('class');
    // then do whatever you want with the class here
}
```

the `alert(..)` is just to prompt if you actually get the correct value, you can delete this usage of course when you get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.test').click(function() {
       if($(this).hasClass('classnameyouarelookingfor')){
        alert($(this).attr('class'));
     }
    });
```