# How to get html element's class tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modernizr

I'm using a custom modernizer config which has selected the features I employ in my page (and only those features).

So, I'd like to simply grab the className of the `<html>` of the page so I can check to see how many `no-` prefixed classes are present (maybe checking `classlist.match(/no-/g).length`) and determine if my javascript should just give up.

It's not clear whether I should use

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html').className
```

or

```
$('html').attr('class')
```

or

```
document.documentElement.className
```

Comment: I don't see any reason not to use any of the three.

Comment: They all work, but you might have cross-browser issues with 1st and 3rd.Second one abstracts this through jquery.

Comment: Any will work, except that you probably need to dereference the `getElementsByTagName()` one since it returns a node list:  `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className`

Comment: jQuery Answer here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400386/get-class-name-using-jquery

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I will go for:

```
document.documentElement.className;
```

Because doesn't involve any function's call, neither an additional layer like jquery. Ideally this one is the cleanest and the fastest.

Answer (score 5):

you can use jQuery [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)` method:

> Determine whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given class.

```
if ( $('html').hasClass('no-something')) {
  // do something here
}
```

Comment: This only works if you already know the class name, which is different than what was asked.

Answer (score 2):

If using plain JS, the equivalent would be:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className
```

Comment: Make that 'plain vanilla', please. I thought I was missing yet another js library until I read the line of code! VanillaJS, sounds like a library!

Comment: I'll quote [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanilla). A major use of `vanilla` is in flavoring ice cream. The most common flavor of ice cream is `vanilla`, and thus most people consider it to be the `"default"` flavor. By analogy, the term `"vanilla"` is sometimes used as a synonym for `"plain"`.

Comment: I would say `plain JS`. (And would use `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className`).

Comment: Each to their own ;) I don't think it's a big deal, but I agree .className is more appropriate - i'll update my answer to reflect both of your points! Thanks

Comment: FWIW I just call it "pure JS"

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery in your project why to not use this one:

```
var classList = $("html").attr('class').split(/\s+/);
var prefix = 'no-';

$.each( classList, function(index, item){
  if (item.substring(0, 2) === prefix) {
    //do something
  }
});
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var allClasses = [];
 var allElements = document.querySelectorAll('*');

 for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
     if (allElements[i].hasAttribute("class")) {
        var classes = allElements[i].className.toString().split(/\s+/);
        for (var j = 0; j < classes.length; j++) {
             var cls = classes[j];
             if (cls && allClasses.indexOf(cls) === -1)
                allClasses.push(cls);
        }
     }
 }

 console.log(allClasses);
```