# get selected option of $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

if i am looping through some jquery objects that are `select` dropdowns, how can I get the class of the selected option using jquery's `$(this)`?

```
elems.each(function(idx, elem) {
    if ($(this).is('select')){
        console.log($(this, "option:selected"))
    }
});
```

does not seem to work.

Comment: What are you trying to do in `console.log`? Print the value of selected option?

Comment: @Vega print the selected option object

Comment: I think you are looking for hasClass http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/ Or if you want to get the classes of $(this) take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400386/get-class-name-using-jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
​elems.each(function(idx, elem) {
    var ref = $(this); // caching $(this)
    if( ref.is('select') ) {
        console.log( ref.find('option:selected') );

        // OR in jQuery Context format
        console.log( $('option:selected', ref) ); // this format internally 
                                                  // called .find() method

        // to get the class
        console.log( ref.find('option:selected').attr('class') );
    }
})​;
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry for this late response. What is the purpose of caching `$(this)`.

Comment: @thomas cause each time you use `$(this)`, it will call function `$()` and need processing. so why the caching. `:)`

Comment: yikes. that is something i did not know. thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there except that the order in which you have passed the argument are not correct. See below,

```
elems.each(function(idx, elem) {
    if ($(elem).is('select')){
        console.log($("option:selected", elem));
    }
});
```

`$("option:selected", this)` in which the first argument is the selector and 2nd argument is the context.

**Note:** The `.each` 2nd argument is the element itself, so you can use `elem` instead of `this`

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/MUC6H/1/

Answer (score 2):

> how can I get the class of the selected option

```
if ($(this).is('select')){
        console.log($(this).find("option:selected").attr("class"));
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DWEY4/

Comment: who is downvoting both these answers and not supplying a comment ??

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the `hasClass` function?

```
elems.each(function(idx, elem) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('select')){
        console.log($(this, "option:selected"))
    }
});
```

Looking at it further, i think your original method will work too if you add a `.` class identifier

```
elems.each(function(idx, elem) {
    if ($(this).is('.select')){
        console.log($(this, "option:selected"))
    }
});
```