# jQuery - Getting the class of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I'm trying to get the class of an element but i don't know the method that will do it.
HTML:

```
<div class="one"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var divclass =  // Over here
    console.log(divclass)
});
```

Can anyone help me?
NOTE: I'm trying to log the class of the div with the class 'one'.

Comment: And why do you need the class

Comment: @adeneo I had to toggle between three classes so i need to get the class name

Comment: besides - duplicate question alert! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400386/get-class-name-using-jquery

Comment: @avaragecoder If you know all of the possibilities, I would recommend `$element.hasClass('.one')` or maybe `$element.is('.one')`.

Comment: @JasonP That wouldn't work because there is 3 classes so i would need to write 3 variables, 3 if/else statements and 6 .hasClass functions, So that would not be dry. NOTE: DRY means Don't Repeat Yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select the target element first. Then you can get its class by using `.attr()` function. Basically `.attr()` will helps you to get any attributes of a particular element.

Please read [here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get a full grip.

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var divclass = $('div').first().attr('class');
    console.log(divclass)
});
```

Here in the above code `.first()` is optional. I just used this to get the `first` element from the element collection. Please read [here](http://api.jquery.com/first/) to know more about it.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/g6Hs6/)

Answer (score 5):

Considering that the div-element is the first div-element in your html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var divclass =  $("div").attr("class"); 
   console.log(divclass)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery `.attr()` method to retrieve class name

```
$(function(){
  var divclass = $("div").attr("class"); 
  console.log(divclass);
});
```