# How to get class name dynamically from element on jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to get the value of the classname like using an index or array? I have this code:

```
<input class="wpsc-buy-now-button wpsc-buy-now-button-64" type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
```

I want to get the wpsc-buy-now-button-64 dynamically. I don't want to use $(".wpsc-buy-button-64"), because my plan is to put it on a variable like so

```
var $classOfBtn = wpsc-buy-now-button-64;
```

64 is an id that I need to compare with another value in a foreach. This changes depending on content.

Comment: I think you're looking for a string literal: `var $classOfBtn = 'wpsc-buy-now-button-64';`

Comment: You can get the list of class names form the element if that is what you are asking about.

Comment: you can get class name through assign an 'id' to input tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML:**
Give an ID to the control.

```
<input id="btn" class="wpsc-buy-now-button wpsc-buy-now-button-64" type="image"
    name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"
    alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $classOfBtn = $('#btn').attr('class').split(' ')[0] + '-64';
    alert($classOfBtn );
});
```

**EDIT:**
Provided your control has the name `submit`, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $allClasses = $("[name='submit']").attr('class').split(' ');
    for(var i=0; i < $allClasses.length; i++)
    {
        // Check $allClasses[i] here.
    }
});
```

Please see this working fiddle for my example: http://jsfiddle.net/jwyF8/

Comment: The 64 is meant to be unknown. I should not define it. What I want is to get all classes and look for that class and pass it to a variable.

Comment: Look for which class? You will get all the classes in an array using `$('#btn').attr('class').split(' ')`.

Comment: Yes. I think that's what I need. I want to get all the classes then find the certain class from there. :)

Comment: Apparently, the element I want to call has no id and just a group of classes. Also, I tried to use alert($allClasses[i]), but it did not run.

Comment: Please see I have updated again. What so you mean by **did not run**?

Comment: It did not show an alert message, which means the script is not running correctly. I tried a simple alert message without the functions, and it run the test message.

Comment: What error are you getting in your browser's Javascript console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function local.givagif.com/:644
(anonymous function)

Comment: Have you included JQuery in your code?

Comment: Yes. This is the whole snippet, just add the alert function inside it:

$(document).ready(function () {
                    var $allClasses = $("[name='submit']").attr('class').split(' ');
                    for(var i=0; i < $allClasses.length; i++)
                    {
                      // Check $allClasses[i] here.
                      alert($allClasses[i]);
                    }
                  });

Comment: I meant, have you included the **JQuery Library** in your HTML? A file with name something like 'jquery-1.10.2.min.js' or a url to the online library?

Comment: I believe so. Also, I am running this in a Wordpress template file.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read the class of the input give it an `id` and then use -

```
var className = $('#id').attr('class');
```

and if you want to make the selector using class, you can store the class name to some variable as you have mentioned-

```
var $classOfBtn = wpsc-buy-now-button-64;
```

and then use it like this -

```
$('.'+$classOfBtn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is what you would have;

```
var $classOfBtn = 'wpsc-buy-now-button-64';
```

this would work just fine:

```
$('.' + $classOfBtn) //note the dot
```

Update:

if you do indeed want to get all classes you'd have to assign some other mean of identifying your `input`, so that it can be retrieved and "asked" for its classes list.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery).

Answer (score 0):

Substitute the string for a literal, and follow the instructions here:

[Get class name using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400386/get-class-name-using-jquery)

It would also be helpful if you could describe what you mean by getting the button dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can put all of classes in array like this:

```
var classArray = $('input').attr('class').split(' ');
// So now you can declare variables
var classbtn1 = classArray[0];
var classbtn2 = classArray[1];
```