# Get part of CSS class as string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Say I had the following 4 divs:

```
<div class="mine-banana"></div>
<div class="mine-grape"></div>
<div class="mine-apple"></div>
<div class="orange"></div>
```

I've discovered I can use the following JQuery selector to get the 3 "mine" divs, but I can't quite figure out how to return all the fruits that are "mine" :)

```
$('[class*=" mine-"]').each(function() {
    var fruit = $(this).????
});
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400386/get-class-name-using-jquery

Comment: Any reason why you're mixing an identifier (`"mine-"`) with data (the fruit)? Separate them into separate attributes. Give them the class "mine" and target them that way. Then store the fruit associated in an attribute called `data-fruit` and get that attribute value

Comment: That makes more sense.  I'll try it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xN42x/)

The best way to accomplish that is to refactor your html, as @Ian pointed it out, for example :

```
<div class="mine" data-mine-fruit="banana"></div>
<div class="mine" data-mine-fruit="grape"></div>
<div class="mine" data-mine-fruit="apple"></div>
<div class="orange"></div>
```

The JS code is straightforward now :

```
var fruits = $('.mine').map(function () {
    return $(this).attr('data-mine-fruit')
});
```

---

If you still want to use your current code, here is a regex-based code

```
var fruits = []
$('[class*=" mine-"], [class^="mine-"]').each(function() {
    fruits.push( this.className.match(/[^a-z0-9_-]?mine-([0-9a-z_-]+)/i)[1] );

})
```

which really works