# Trying to hide a div if the heading of the page = "x"

Tags: javascript, if-statement, visibility

I'm trying to do some tweeking of a wordpress theme, and hide a certain `div` only on certain pages with some javascript, the code I have come up with is:

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName("page-title") === "NEW ARRIVALS"){
    document.getElementById("pull_9").style.visibility="hidden";
}else if(document.getElementsByClassName("page-title") === "SALE"){
    document.getElementById("pull_9").style.visibility="hidden";
}else{
    document.getElementById("pull_9").style.visibility="visible";
};
```

but its not working, I know that getElementByClassName() is not supper supported yet but it will do for these requirement.

can anyone see why this is not working? its probably something very simple (I'm new to javascript) but i cant theoretically see why it shouldn't work.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("page-title")` will not return you a string, it will return a collection of elements.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is used to get you a list of element nodes, not a string.

Comment: Try using jquery, probably it's included in your theme (it is generalized), the fact that is not compatible with all browsers, it's a good reason to change. In jquery would be: if($(".page-title").hasClass("NEW ARRIVALS")), but classes cannot have two words, so there is sth you are doing wrong, "new arrival" are two classes.

Comment: i think jQuery will be the way too go, but im not trying to get the class name, im trying to say if a heading with the class of `.page-title` is "NEW ARRIVALS" then hide this other div.

Comment: well then @ShoutItWebSolutions, that isn't the method to use. You should use `var className = $('.myclass').attr('class');` to get the class name.

Comment: @ShoutItWebSolutions: jQuery is not the answer to all of the world's problems. What is preventing you from using this: `document.getElementsByClassName("page-title")[0].innerText == 'NEW ARRIVALS'` ?

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400386/get-class-name-using-jquery)

Comment: @abhitalks If his site already has jQuery on board why not use it? :)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko: I am in agreement with you. But, will that solve the underlying problem? Unless he gets the concepts right, Op will do the same mistake with jQuery. Op will do the same mistake with any library for that matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are `NEW ARRIVALS` & `SALE` content of those elements?

If the `page-title` refers to the `<title>` tag, then you can use that

```
document.querySelector('title').textContent
```

If the `page-title` refers to ONE item or the FIRST item you can try:

```
document.querySelector('.page-title').textContent
```

Alternatively ...

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('page-title');

for (var i = 0, len = elem.length; i < len; i++) {

  if (elem[i].textContent === 'NEW ARRIVALS' || 
      elem[i].textContent === 'SALE') {
    document.getElementById('pull_9').style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
    break;     
  }
}
```

Or ....

```
for (var i = 0, len = elem.length; i < len; i++) {

  if (elem[i].textContent.match(/NEW ARRIVALS|SALE/)) {
    document.getElementById("pull_9").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    break;    
  }
}
```

There are usually many ways to achieve the same objective.

If it is only one element that your code refers to ... then for example

```
if (document.querySelector('.page-title').textContent.match(/NEW ARRIVALS|SALE/)) {
  document.getElementById('pull_9').style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a set of elements. You would want to iterate through the set, or `Array.filter` the set…or simply get the first element in the set via bracket notation.

`var set = document.getElementsByClassName('whatever');`

`var item = document.getElementsByClassName('whatever')[0];`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName

Also, `getElementsByClassName` is currently supported by all desktop and mobile browsers:

http://caniuse.com/#search=getelementsbyclassname

Answer (score 1):

If jQuery is ok you can use `:contains` selector and `toggle` method

```
var show = !$('.page-title:contains(NEW ARRIVALS), .page-title:contains(SALE)')
            .length; 
$('#pull_9').toggle(show);
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/aFE7Z/).