# Extracting A Particular Class With JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have some lments, like this:

```
<lment class="item-45 big top hold"></lment>
<lment class="item-46 big top grid"></lment>
<lment class="item-47 big top stop"></lment>
```

I can select them using:

```
lments = $('[class^="item"]');
```

But how do I get the "45", "46", and "47"?

I'm starting with something like this:

```
itsClass = lments[i].getAttribute('class');
```

I don't know where to go from here, but want to end up with the equivalent of this:

```
lmentsItemNum = someExtractorFunction(itsClass);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get class name using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400386/get-class-name-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.each($("lment"), function(a, e) {
    alert($(e).attr("class").split('-')[1].split(' ')[0]);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<lment class="item-45 big top hold"></lment>
<lment class="item-46 big top grid"></lment>
<lment class="item-47 big top stop"></lment>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you need to get the class name at the beginning you can do something like this using **[`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)**

1. Use **[`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)** to iterate over jQuery object
2. Extract digits from class name using **[split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** and return
3. For getting the result array use **[get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/)**

```js
lments = $('[class^="item"]').map(function() {
  return this.className.split(' ')[0].split('-')[1];
}).get();
console.log(lments);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<lment class="item-45 big top hold"></lment>
<lment class="item-46 big top grid"></lment>
<lment class="item-47 big top stop"></lment>
```

If not in this format then

```js
lments = $('[class*="item-"]').map(function() {
  var a;
  this.className.split(' ').forEach(function(v){
  if(v.match(/^item-\d+$/))
    a=v.split('-')[1];
  }); 
  if(a)
  return a;
}).get();
console.log(lments);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<lment class="item-45 big top hold"></lment>
<lment class="item-46 big top grid"></lment>
<lment class="item-big top grid"></lment>
<lment class="item-47 big top stop"></lment>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating array , utilizing `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` argument `/\d+/` to return digit within `Element.className` as item within array

```js
var lments = document.querySelectorAll("[class^=item]");

function someExtractorFunction(items) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    arr.push(items[i].className.match(/\d+/)[0])
  return arr
}

var lmentsItemNum = someExtractorFunction(lments);

console.log(lmentsItemNum)
```

```html
<lment class="item-45 big top hold"></lment>
<lment class="item-46 big top grid"></lment>
<lment class="item-47 big top stop"></lment>
```