# what is Efficient way to find tr using classname in ie

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having 1000 tr in table.i want to find tr using classname in ie.what is Efficient way to find tr using classname in ie

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get class name using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400386/get-class-name-using-jquery)

Comment: "1000 records in a table in IE" already sounds rather inefficient

Comment: You surely just doesn't need to 'get' all of them...

Answer (score -1):

You can use either DOM's native function `getElementsByClassName('classname')` or jQuery selector `$('.classname')` to find the target element.

See [getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)
See [selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) in jQuery

Comment: The **DOM**'s function, not JavaScript's. And answering rubbish, zero-effort, unclear, soon-to-be-closed-and-deleted questions isn't useful.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName('.classname')` will look for elements with class `..classname`