# jquery get the class that starts with specific string (not the element)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm turning my Twitter bootstrap flashmessages in notifications for which i need to get it's type (like, success, info, error etc).

This can be done by getting a class like alert-success and substring it.

How can I get the class from my current element which start with a certain part. (in this case `alert-`)

Example element:

`<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">...</div>`

**I need to get the class and not the element**

Comment: Put the alert type in its own `data-*` attribute and read that out when needed. Hacking around a `className` string isn't a great idea

Comment: Unless I'm missing something - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400386/get-class-name-using-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a simple regex match on elements containing `alert-` in `class` attribute.

```
var cls = $('div[class*="alert-"]').attr("class").match(/alert-(.*)\s?/)[0];
```